# What are good values for PSU voltages?

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I have an odd computer I'm trying to fix that will crash only during the setup of an OS(crashes on every OS I've tried so far) It's not overheating and it is stripped down as much as possible and I've tried multiple harddrives, and memtest86+ can run on it for 3 hours without a crash or fail.

So, I was a bit stumped and was looking in the BIOS for possible causes and found a hardware monitor that shows PSU voltages. They are:

```
VCORE:  1.432V
3.3V:   3.136V
5V:     5.273
12V:    12.144V
```

I thought the 3.3V looked a little low, but I'm not really sure on how "bad" that is.

So, **what are the good ranges for the voltages on each CPU rail?**

Comment: What do you mean by crash?  When you load Windows for example, what error are you seeing?

Comment: @Black sorry, I mean sporadic reboots. No errors or anything, just random hard reboots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal voltage +/- 5%.  So 12v would be 11.4 to 12.6 for example.